# Submitting form (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, forms

I have a page full of links like this:

```
<a href="javascript:Window('args')"> text here </a>
```

When the link is clicked a window pops up (using Javascript). The Javascript also creates the contents of the new window. (with `innerHTML`)

The content consists of a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/doaction.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="hashcode">
    /* code to insert data (textfields etc.) */
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

What i'm trying to do is:

1. Filter all the links i need
2. *clicking* the first link to open the popup window
3. *clicking* the **submit** button to send the data

The first step shouldn't be to hard and i can figure that out myself.
However i have no clue how to do step 2 (but i can probably find some tutorials on how to click a link in Python) and step 3.

So any help on how to start with step 3 is highly appreciated.

(Also if i *really* shouldn't be doing this in Python, let me know)

Comment: Urgh. There's no reason to use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol in HTML links these days. Leave the `href` empty and use `onclick` instead.

Comment: @Daniel I assume it is not a page the OP has written :)

Comment: @Ashy you're completely right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) to make a POST request to the script the form is submitting to.

```
import urllib, urllib2
url = '/doaction.php'
data= {'hashcode': 'blah', 'name':'blahblah', 'type':'blahblahblah'}
request = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(data))
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Ok, that looks managable. I can't find any info on the syntax for the data string. Let's say i have 3 inputs with values: "hashcode", "name", "type", how would my data string look like ? The link you provided says it has to be a buffer in the *application/x-www-form-urlencoded format*, but i have no clue what that means.

Comment: You can use urlencode.. data = urllib.urlencode({"username":user, "password":pass})